# Android Studio After Google Sign In

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I used firebase login to get Google Sign in to work on my app. My group and I have been having an issue for the past couple weeks. We don't know how to change screens to a new activity after the user signs in.

This is our MainActivity.java code

```html
package com.plannerangelica.tmr;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import static com.plannerangelica.tmr.R.styleable.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    private String mUsername;
    private String mPhotoUrl;
    



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //  add these just after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// Initialize Firebase Auth
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
            // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        } else {
            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }
            Log.i("User Name:", mUsername);
        }


    }
    }
```

and SignInActivity.java

```js
package com.plannerangelica.tmr;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private SignInButton mSignInButton;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        // Assign fields
        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        // Set click listeners
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        // Initialize FirebaseAuth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
    private void handleFirebaseAuthResult(AuthResult authResult) {
        if (authResult != null) {
            // Welcome the user
            FirebaseUser user = authResult.getUser();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Go back to the main activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
            }
        }
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and activity_sign_in.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="sign_in"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What does your log say?

Comment: well our event log says everything is working fine. All our code works we just dont know how to get from the google sign in to our next page, the menu

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  startActivity(new Intent(this, activity_sign_in.class));
```

after the user is signed in i.e.  inside this

```
else {
            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }
            Log.i("User Name:", mUsername);
        }
```